# Uploading to NAS servers from flakey Internet connections

Tags: fine-uploader, nas

I'm trying to find a solution that will allow photographers based in developing countries with flakey Internet connections to upload TIFF files (each around 100 Mb in size) to my NAS server. As connections frequently snap, it would be good to find a way to ensure that uploads can continue where they left off once the connection is restored, similar to the way they do with Dropbox, without corrupting files. Can Fine Uploader do this? I am not very tech-savvy, so please forgive me if this seems like an ignorant question!

Comment: Yes, it can, but this is not an appropriate question for stack overflow. I would suggest deleting this question and having a look at http://fineuploader.com for further info. If you have any specific behavioral questions, you can open up an issue in the GitHub issue tracker.

Comment: This is not an answer, but this article on Offline-First Design might be useful to you: http://alistapart.com/article/offline-first

Comment: I'm sorry if this is the wrong place. At fineuploader.com it says that any questions should be posted here and tagged fine-uploader. :-)

Comment: for future reference: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please also keep in mind that Stack Overflow (and Fine Uploader) are both geared towards developers. If you plan on integrating Fine Uploader or any other upload library into your application, you will need the help of a developer.